# Remote key fob doesn't work unless the steering wheel is locked?

Tags: vw, golf, key, central-locking

I recently bought a **2010 Golf Plus** (based on Golf Mk6), and I'm having a
weird problem. The dealer gave me a classic remote key fob, but he also
made another key without the remote function, just a regular key. Both of
them work fine, unlock the doors and start the car.

***The problem is, the lock/unlock/boot buttons on the remote key do not work
unless the steering wheel is locked.***

So every time I turn off the car, I have to lock the steering wheel by turning it around, get out of the car and lock it by pressing a button. If I don't do this I have to lock it manually.

Anyone ever heard of this, and is there a way it can be disabled?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

This is a pretty odd problem but normally the keyless entry disables based off of the key buzzer or the ignition being in "ACC" or "ON". VW's I'm not sure which off the top of my head it is (buzzer or being in "ON") but I do know normal operation when in the ON position means the keyless entry is disabled.

This would lead me to believe there is some type of fault in the wheel lock assembly and it gets corrected when the bolt slides up to the locking position. Perhaps there is just some dirt causing the key buzzer to not drop in place. Try spraying some wd-40 in the key hole. Slide the key in and out several times and wipe it off. Repeat till you do not see much dirt left on the key when bringing it out.

Better example of what I mean. The key buzzer is getting stuck after putting your key in so then when you take the key out it still thinks a key is inserted.   When you jostle the wheel and the locking bolt springs into place it causes the key buzzer to fall to its normal position so its able to detect that the key is out and then the keyless feature is enabled.

Its nothing new that VW's around these years have huge problems with these wheel lock assembly's already but I have not heard of this problem before.